# Составить запрос в цикле?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица `атрибуты_товаров`. Хранит значения `id_товара` и `id_значения_атрибута`. У меня есть массив, `id_значений_атрибутов`. Есть так же таблица `значение_атрибутов`, где есть `id_значения_атрибутов` и `значение_атрибутов`.

Примерное моей действие

```
foreach ($attr as $item){
   SELECT * FROM таблица_атрибутов 
       WHERE id_значения_атрибутов == $item['id_attr']
}
```

Так вот а как вернуть массив полученного результата?

Comment: если была бы структура таблиц, легче можно было написать запрос sql

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
$idList = '';
$k=0;
foreach ($attr as $item){
    if ($k>0) $idList .= ',';
    $idList .= $item['id_attr'];
    $k++;
}

SELECT * FROM таблица_атрибутов WHERE id_значения_атрибутов in ( $idList )
```